# Смена URL адреса страницы в JS без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется пагинация

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="?page=1&price=0-3500&tip_linz=krutie_linzi&brand=aqua-oko">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page=2&price=0-3500&tip_linz=krutie_linzi&brand=aqua-oko">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page=3&price=0-3500&tip_linz=krutie_linzi&brand=aqua-oko">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page=4&price=0-3500&tip_linz=krutie_linzi&brand=aqua-oko">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Данные в `<ul>` подгружаются через AJAX и заменяются каждый раз, когда кликаем по `<a>` 
(POST запрос на back-end, в ответ получаем строку, содержащую новые ссылки для пагинации и вставляем их в `<ul>`)

Нужно при клике на `<a>` достать значение "href" и заменить, без перезагрузки страницы, текущий url на "sitename.ru/**href**"

Пытался сделать вот так, но увы, работает только при первом клике

```
    $('ul a').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        window.history.pushState('', '', href);

    });
```

А нужно, что бы каждый раз url менялся

Comment: пагинация. я даже слова такого не знал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том что ваш элемент пропадает после AJAX запроса, вместе со всеми хуками которые вы на него навесили. Решить это можно так:

```
$('body').on('click', "ul a", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    window.history.pushState('', '', href);
});
```

Либо каждый раз после запроса заново вешать хук на новые элементы. Как вам удобней.